# Force Chrome/Firefox developer tools to render edits more immediately like Firebug

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-devtools, firebug, firefox-developer-tools

In Firebug, when you edit an HTML or CSS element, the changes take effect on the screen after a short pause, even while still editing. In the Chrome and Firefox developer tools, the changes only take effect when you lose focus of the editing.

See a comparison below of editing in Firebug, where updates are made to the page while still editing the HTML:

[image]

Compare that to Chrome, which does not update the page after pausing:

[image]

This is extremely infuriating as it leads to less productivity in being able to change items on the fly with somewhat immediate feedback. With the Chrome/Firefox developer tools, you have to type, lose focus, see the changes, re-focus, type again, and then lose focus again.

Is there anyway to make this behavior on Chrome/Firefox more like Firebug? If not, is there any quicker way to see the updates without having to lose focus and re-focus on every little change? There's features in these other two developer toolkits I would like to use, but the inability to get more fluid edits is something very difficult to overcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Firefox DevTools there is currently no way to let their Inspector do the updates immediately. Though there's already [bug 815464](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=815464) filed to change this behavior.

A better workflow for them is to hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> after you've edited the value. Then you can open the editor again by pressing <kbd>Space</kbd>. Doing so you don't lose the focus.

The Chrome DevTools don't offer a way to do live updates when changing the HTML, neither. Because I couldn't find a related issue to improve the behavior, I requested this in [issue 546883](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=546883).

Their *Elements* panel allows a similar workflow as the Firefox DevTools' *Inspector* panel. There you can start and stop inline editing by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> or use the bigger HTML editor by pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> and stop editing via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Unfortunately Chrome's *Elements* panel does not focus the part you edited, so you either always start at the first attribute or you edit the whole element.

Comment: Thank you for the finding/filing the appropriate bugs and noting a better workflow for these developer tools.